# Facebook Feed Dialogue showing code instead of content

Tags: facebook

I have been struggling to get a facebook "post to wall" dialogue to show on my site but all it shows is code on that page.

Here is what should happen:

1. A visitor comes to my site and clicks a custom "Share" button I made
2. The visitor is then redirected them to the feed dialogue box on a different page and they share my page.
3. They then proceed to download what I offered.

I made a facebook app and then copied the code from the facebook developer page and filled out everything I need, but anytime I click the share it takes me to a page with all the code instead.

[image]

Comment: You have 10 rep now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try this, load the javascript SDK:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
              channelUrl : 'URL_TO_CHANNEL_FILE', // Channel File optional
              status     : true, // check login status
              cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
              xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));
    </script>
```

Then add a listener to your button, let's say your button has the id, `bt-download`

```
<script>    
$(document).on("click", "#bt-download", function(){
       var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: 'link to your webpage',
            picture: "url to the picture you want size 90px x 90px",
            name: 'the name you want',
            caption: 'your caption',
            description: 'your description',
            display: 'popup'
       };

       function callback(response) {
           if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
            //here you can redirect the user to the download page
           } else {
             alert('Post was not published.');
           }
       }
       FB.ui(obj, callback);

            });
</script>
```

Comment: I have never coded before. I was using common sense to code everything so I still have a question about what you said. Do I save both scripts on one file and what extension should save it as? I plan on naming it index and putting it in another folder in my hosting account. Thanks though, extremely helpful

Comment: You don't need to create any js file just put this in the middle of your HTML code, the first script put it just after the <body> tag, don't forget to put this after the <body> <div id="fb-root"></div>, the other one just put it on the bottom of your file

Comment: Can you be more specific? What doesn't work? Do you have any errors on your console (using firebug or google chrome developer tools)

Comment: There is no error. It is indifferent. It does nothing when i test it. Still thesame page. If you have time and want you can add me on skype and I will show you via realtime so that maybe it will be much clearer.

Comment: Sure, but it must be quick